# _id field compared to index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm planning to add a Collection to a mongodb database that will have a text field that should be unique for each Document. Lookups from this Collection will almost always be based on this field. This field can contain as many as 100+ chars.

My question is, should this field be the `_id` field, or should I just add an index for it? What would the performance impact for either approach be?

Comment: Would the text/_id ever change? Are other documents using it as a key?

Comment: @WiredPrairie: The ID would never change and yes, other documents would use this field as a key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use your unique text as `_id`.

It will reduce data size and eliminate an index. [Here](http://www.slideshare.net/bdarfler/optimizing-mongodb-lessons-learned-at-localytics-9515255) is the reference. 9th page will guide you.

Comment: There is a lot more than just data size to consider here, for one sharding